# Math.round() as v-model return value

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an issue with `Math.round()` used with `v-model` in the following template:

```
<v-text-field v-model="rounded" />
```

`rounded` is a computed property:

```
rounded: {
  get() {
    return this.value; 
  },
  set (val) {
    this.value = Math.round(val);
    console.log(this.value);
  }
}
```

*Expected results seen in `v-text-field`:*

```
   Input    |  Expected Value  |  Actual Value
===============================================
   1.12     |       1          |   1.12
   1.6      |       2          |   2
```

Why doesn't the `v-text-field` show `1` when I enter `1.12`?

Comment: how are you setting the 1.6 value? Are you using rounded or this.value directly ?

Comment: v-model = "rounded"

Comment: it's working fine for 1.6. I know  one part of solution : this is happening because the int value of returned value has changed from 1 to 2. 
in case 1.12 the int value (1) will not change, and this is the root of the issue. because I tried Math.round(val +1) and it works fine : 1.12 => 2 , 1.6 => 3

Comment: @mohamedhajaji I deleted it. This issue might be specific to Vuetify's `<v-text-field>` because it works if I use a simple `input` number field.

Comment: this is what i think too. thanks Liza

Comment: added an answer by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main cause is, you are changing the **value** not **rounded** variable, so if you do like below , hope your problem will solved.

```
  <v-text-field v-model="rounded" :value="val" @change="OnChange" />
```

and add val property into data block:

```
    data(){
    return:{
    val:0.00
    }
   }
```

No need to do anything for computed property, just write the OnChange method into methods block like below:

```
methods:{
OnChange(newVal){
this.val = Math.round(newVal);
this. rounded=this.val;
 }
}
```

Comment: yes, this works with v-model and :value together. 
unfortunately for me i can't use v-model, i have the value  from a very complicated array. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Rather than bind to a computed property, watch the value and update it.

```html
<v-text-field v-model="rounded" />
```

```js
    {
      data() {
          return {
            rounded: 0
          }
        },

        watch: {
          rounded(val) {
            let newVal = Math.round(val);
            if (newVal !== val) {
                this.val = newVal
            }
            // or even simply this.val = Math.round(this.val) without the check ...
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it's too complicated in my case. In fact, the v-text-field has the value from an array. and it's more complicated  to do  a deep watch.